# JSS Default Angular App Build Error: Cannot find name 'Exclude'

Tags: jss

1. Install JSS:

> npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli

2. create default react app - runs in Chrome:

> jss create jss-react-app **react**
>
> cd jss-react-app
>
> jss start

3. create default angular app and attempt to run:

> jss create jss-angular-app **angular**
>
> cd jss-angular-app
>
> jss start

**Expected**: build and run, just like react app

**Observed**: cannot build due to build error.

> chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 3.26 kB [entry] [rendered]
>
> ERROR in node_modules/apollo-angular/types.d.ts(9,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
> src/app/jss-graphql.service.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Test/jss-angular-app/node_modules/apollo-angular/types"' has no exported member 'TypedVariables'.

Gotta be something *stupid* on my part, since I can't find anything on the web about this error. Thanks!

Windows 7, Chrome 70.0.3538.102
JSS: 9.0.6
Angular: 6.1.10
AngularCLI: 6.2.7
Node: 10.13.0

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pin your `apollo-angular` version to exactly 1.1.1 in the `package.json` (remove the `^`), then run `npm i` again:

https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/0292a05077c4ef21b668eb9c30412f57620c3779/samples/angular/package.json#L66

Unfortunately if packages are installed without a lock file (i.e. using `npm` since the sample ships with a yarn lockfile) to limit using newer versions the `apollo-angular` is installed with a version designed for a later version of Angular than the app has.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that TypedVariables last existed in apollo-angular in version 1.4, so I pinned that version. Then I got an error where Exclude wasn't defined, so I pinned typescript to 2.9.2. Therefore, after creating the default angular app and changing to that folder, run:

> npm install apollo-angular@1.4 --save-exact
>
> npm install typescript@2.9.2 --save-exact

BEFORE trying to build and start the app and it will build and run just fine.